# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting variable (T_VARIABLE)

Tags: php, pdo, php-parse-error

I've got error on defined-function and from `error_reporting(E_ALL);`

There are errors `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting variable (T_VARIABLE) in C:\xampp\htdocs\bs4\func.php on line 4`

Here is my code

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
require_once "condb.php";
function noproblem(time,suggest,phone,eat,problem){ // Here is line 4

  $sql="insert into data(time,suggest,phone,eat,problem) values(?,?,?,?,?)";
  $stmt=$cn->prepare($sql);
  $stmt->bindParam("1",time);
  $stmt->bindParam("2",suggest);
  $stmt->bindParam("3",phone);
  $stmt->bindParam("4",eat);
  $stmt->bindParam("5",problem);

  try {
    $stmt->execute();
    echo "ok!";
  } catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getTraceAsString();
  }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In PHP variables have to start with a $:

```
function noproblem($time,$suggest,$phone,$eat,$problem){
```

The same applies to all other variables in the example.

Answer (score 1):

Variables starts with "$" sign.

Answer (score 1):

If you are certain that all variables starts with "$" sign, your PHP version might be the cause.